# Showing wrong password while redirect site from http to https

Tags: asp.net, iis, sql-server-2012, iis-8.5

I have migrated the site from HTTP to HTTPS in IIS8.5 using URL redirect module. But while redirect the front end site to https showing wrong password dialog box though providing correct credentials. I could see that cookies are not storing while the site is redirecting.

What should be done so that cookies can be stored as well?

Comment: This is expected behavior. IIS (and all web servers) treat http and https websites as entirely different websites. You should redirect your user to the https site before any interaction.

Comment: Could you please elaborate how it can be done i.e. how the user can be redirected to https site?

Comment: Check here http://codingstill.com/2010/08/url-rewriting-in-iis7/. It is an article I have written about rewriting in IIS, see the sample for *Redirect to HTTPS*. This will switch all requests to run to the https site.

Comment: I have used the following rewrite rule:-
<rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
</rule>


The site is redirecting to https but showing wrong password the form data is not storing.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: (I would suggest you add your config to the question itself, to prevent it from closing).